# Customizing a dialog's field sizes in Moqui

Tags: moqui

Does anyone have a hint how to customize field length in a dialog? A dialog opened via container-dialog. The one that pops on me has items with inadequate sizes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you explore xml-form-1.6.xsd you will find attributes there for elements like text-line, text-area and all other types. With explanations. (a good XML editor will auto-suggest the elements and attributes as you type, using these .xsd files).

Some examples:

```
<text-line size="30" maxlength="50" />

<text-area cols="60" rows="6" />
```

You can also use 'field-layout' element and its sub-elements to set out your form.

(Assuming you don't mean length of a data field in a database).

Comment: Thanks. And no I did not mean lenght of a data field :-). You are my first responder. Cheers.

Comment: This applies to simple field. What about drop-down? Can I customize its width and/or length? I foung an atribute size, but that did not work as I expected.

Comment: What Moqui version are you using? If you are using the last release 6.2  or before you can use style="chosen-small" or chosen-medium, chosen-wide, chosen-wider, chosen-widest, as suits. As noted in the .xsd this is a 'hack' to fix a bug which I understand has been resolved in current commits.

Comment: I am using the latest release, it says 2.0.0. My attempt failed with a strange outcome. I typed the style="chosen=widest" into the drop-down setup. Nothing happened. I checked the source code of the page and I came accross this  <select name="fromPartyId" class=" chosen-widest" id="NewInvoiceForm_fromPartyId" size="100">. There is an extra space at the beginning of the chosen-widest value. Could that be it?

Comment: The last release was 1.6.2 around l\ate March 2016. You are using the next release (not yet released). I think it was around mid-April that I noted the style="chosen-xxx" work-around was removed. Actually I understand there are some major changes being made to all of this side of things. Unfortunately I am not yet familiar with these changes, so cannot help you here.